# Are subjects/ observables good to share async data between components (pages) in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-services

Lets say we have:

1. Array of chat rooms
2. Each room has an array of messages
3. Rooms and messages in them are changed asynchronously via WebSockets.

The best way to solve it in "Angular2 way" was via `ReplaySubject` [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/34402436).

Where we have to subscribe for rooms change `ChatService.rooms.subscribe(...`, subscribe for message change, then unsubscribe everything...

Isn't it better just to use plain array `[]` in a Service across Components, and when a new room/message is created just to push that data into array ?

Or maybe i'm doing something wrong.

```
export class ChatService {
 private _rooms: ReplaySubject<Room[]> = new ReplaySubject(1);
 rooms: Observable<Room []> = this._rooms.asObservable();

 private socket;

 private _selectedRoom: ReplaySubject<Room> = new ReplaySubject(1);
 selectedRoom: Observable<Room> = this._selectedRoom.asObservable();

 constructor(private UserService:UserService) {
    this.socket = io.connect(window.location.origin, {
        'query': 'token=' + UserService.token
    });
    this.socket.on('existingRooms', (data) => {
        this._rooms.next(data.rooms);
    });
 }

 createNewRoom(string: string) {
     this.socket.emit('createNewRoom', {name: string});

     this.socket.on('newRoomCreated', (data) => {
         this._rooms.first().subscribe((rooms)=> {
            rooms.unshift(data)
            this._rooms.next(rooms);
         }, err => console.error);
     });
    }
```

I can't use `BehaviorSubject` because i don't have initial value;

I have to call `.first()` each time to get current value of ReplaySubject.

I have to subcribe/unsubscribe every component in order to avoid memory leaks.